# rxjs never returns when ajax fails

Tags: rxjs

Given this standard rxjs ajax example, can someone please explain why none of the exit points are hit when the target site does not exist or is not available?

I cannot figure it out, even with a timeout nothing ever comes back, no error or anything. In this instance the call itself in Chrome console fails with net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED but my subscription is stuck and never completes.

How can we handle this in rxjs ajax? It seems such a fundamental problem.

Update: This is rxjs 6.6.7

```
const obs$ = ajax({
    url: 'http://sitedoesnotexist.com',
    timeout: 10000
  }).pipe(
    map(res => console.log(res)),
    catchError(error => {
      console.error(error);
      return of(error);
    })
  );
   
  obs$.subscribe({
    next: value => console.log(value),
    error: err => console.log(err),
    complete: () => console.log('Done')
  });
```

Comment: Perhaps you meant to use `tap()` instead of `map()`? At that point, your observable returns nothing (`undefined`) since `console.log()` returns nothing.

Comment: Good point however sadly not, same result, nothing logged or errored

Comment: That code works fine when I pasted it into a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ebhzhu?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts).  Maybe you have a fliter in your Dev Tools console?

Comment: I also see no problem with the code  you gave us. Do you have something else ?

Comment: Sorry, updated question, it is version 6.6.7. @BizzyBob yes, it works for me too in stackblitz, but perhaps is a problem on 6.6.7

Comment: I created a codesandbox with 6.6.7 and it works in there as well so must be some issue with my app

Comment: One final entry to close this out. Seems like the issue is I had another version of xmlhttprequest installed that was causing havoc. When I removed that it started to work as expected